# Integratable business planning web-app with API

Tags: web-apps, api, business-intelligence, rest

I'm looking for a web based business planning app, which provides opportunity to fill in historic and plan data, and to continuously extend it with actual data which compares to the plan. It's important to customize the business plan's block (eg. manufacturing, sales, finances) and that these modules can communicate and can be validated based on external criteria (eg. if the output of manufacturing is 300, that amount should be assigned to the sales for a given month). Also it's useful to have reports in different formats, supported by charts. It's not for our personal use but to integrate it to a working system which handles the incoming business plans so ideally it has an API which makes it flexible to use.

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: Where do you get the data (ex: 300) from? If it comes from an external system, in what format? Do you have developers who can do the plumbing if needed?

Answer (score 2):

> It's important to customize the business plan's block

This may not be a direct answer, but cloud tools such as [kintone](https://www.kintone.com/) or Zoho Creator are flexible online databases (aPaas) that can be built up with drag and drop. They are not out-of-the-box-business-planning-apps, so it's not going to immediately solve what you need. These tools are more like lego blocks to build up the database tables that will hold the values that you would need, except that they have more UI capabilities involved so they are pretty easy to use in terms of GUI. I know that both tools can have their table structure modified while there's data inside them, which really helps while it's even in operation.

> if the output of manufacturing is 300, that amount should be assigned to the sales for a given month

Workflow can be set up in kintone for every table (or kintone "app") that you create. Once set up, you can have the workflow assigned to different users depending on values inputted into other columns (or kintone "fields"). This can be set up without coding. Zoho also has workflow capabilities which looks pretty deep (sorry, I haven't looked much into this), and it's kind of semi-coding. You define the workflow with the GUI, which automatically creates a script for the workflow.

> Also it's useful to have reports in different formats, supported by charts.

Charts are available for each table you create in kintone, in forms of bar charts, line charts, pivot tables etc

> It's not for our personal use but to integrate it to a working system which handles the incoming business plans so ideally it has an API which makes it flexible to use.

There's open REST API for kintone, with documents listed on their developer page.
https://developer.kintone.io
Each kintone app can generate an Authkey that can simply be used for the authentication process when using the API.

You can get a free dev account from the site to try out building the apps and using the APIs to see if it would actually fit your needs. There are APIs for CRUD functions for the tables, processing workflows, uploading/downloading files and so on.

I hope this helps, but sorry in advance if you were looking for more out-of-the-box tools.

Answer (score 0):

YOu should try out [WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com/rapid/) Rapid app development platform.  It uses an API Driven Development approach, where you can not just integrate with external APIs easily, it also auto-generates comprehensive REST APIs for the app you are trying to build.  For instance, it auto-generates all the CRUD REST APIs for the DB entities that you are creating in your app.